# how to update max value of a column in update statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is some test data

```
CREATE TABLE ranks (
    user_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    rank INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ranks
VALUES
    (1, 6),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 5);
```

I want to update the value of maximum rank but it is giving me error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: update ranks set max(rank) = 10 FROM ranks;
```

The query I am using is

```
update ranks set max(rank) = 10 FROM ranks;
```

Comment: What would you do if max(rank) is already greater then 10? So how about the row (4,12)?

Comment: This is only dummy data. In my real scenario I want to update the geometry which has maximum area by assigning union of its neighbors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
update ranks 
set rank = 10 
where rank = (select max(rank) in ranks)
```

Note that this may update multiple if there are two rank with same max value

to update only one of it

```
update ranks
set rank = 10
where user_id = ( 
   select user_id from ranks 
   order by rank desc
   limit 1
)
```

Comment: ah! but I want to update only 1. Doesn't matter which one but do not want overlap of values.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=770640cd628af0c7744aab01df91cc3c)

```
UPDATE ranks r
SET rank = 10
FROM (
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM ranks 
    ORDER BY rank DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) s
WHERE r.user_id = s.user_id
```